# Drag coefficient in a incline photovoltaic

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

i want to calculate the drag coefficient of a photovltaic that it's constantly changing angle. Is there a way to measure the Cd in any time?

Edit: i want to calculate the Cd to have the Drag of the plate in any time, so Cd and D are unknown but i know the speed of air.

Comment: What is a photovoltaic doing flying around?

Comment: the base of  photovoltaic is fixed, but the solar panel (plate) changes its angle depending on the sun